# Centering Image

Tags: center, css

Hi have the following code appneded three times:

```
<div class="bio">
    <div class="bio-icon"><img src="/images/icon_location.png" alt="Location" /></div>
    <div class="bio-content">
        <div class="bio-title">location:</div>
        <div class="bio-text">' . $obj[0] . '</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In each case, the image inside bio-icon div is different (it is different width and height). 
Basically, there would be an icon, with a text next to it. I want the text to be centered (vertically), but I don't know what to do since the icons each have different heights! What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
.bio {
  display:table;
}

.bio-icon, bio-content {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The only problem with this is IE7 doesn't recognize css table properties so you might have to use jquery to fix in IE7

Answer (score 0):

you can use vertical-align property to center the text vertically [w3 link here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

For different size icon issue, use fixed width and height in css

```
.bio-icon
{
  height:50px;
}
```

This will automatically resize your icon/image.